# How to change the queue name of all the scheduled jobs in Linux?

Tags: linux, task-queue

I have an application where jobs are fired sequentially with a set priority. Now it is fired and I am in midway. Still there are lot of jobs which are pending and are queued up. Now I want to change the queue name of all the scheduled jobs to the queue which is not loaded much (I know which one to load). Doing `bmod -q <queue_name> <job_id>` is not possible as there are hundreds of jobs in line.
Can anyone suggest me a quick way to do this? I tried with something like this:

```
bjobs | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed '1d' | xargs bmod -q high
```

But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd guess `xargs -n1` so that each bmod command is only passed one job_id?